# jquery :visible selector not working on webkit

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, webkit

I need to select the one visible span element in a list inside a div like so: `$('#videoDesc > span:visible')` or `$('#videoDesc > span').filter(':visible')` and it doesn't work in webkit

These span elements have `display: none;` set in the stylsheet (I tested removing this and nothing changed). On the style tag of one of them I set its display to *inline*.

The span elements display is modified using jQuery's show() and hide() functions.

If I call `$('#videoDesc > span:hidden');` from the chrome console I get all the elements everytime, doesn't matter which of them I've called `show()` on. Likewise `$('#videoDesc > span:visible');` gets me an empty list: `[]` everytime.

In firefox and IE I don't have this problem.

I copied this from the chrome console. As you can see span element *videoDesc-1* has a `style="display: inline;"` and it still appears when using `:hidden`

```
$('#videoDesc > span').filter(':hidden');
[<span id="videoDesc-1" style="display: inline;">…</span> ,
<span id="videoDesc-2">…</span> , <span id="videoDesc-3">…</span> , 
<span id="videoDesc-4">…</span>]
```

Is this some sort of webkit bug?

I was able to work around it doing this:

```
$('#videoDesc > span').each(function(i, e) {
    if (this.style.display != 'none') {
        ...
    }
});
```

But it bothers me as it seems like a *wrong* solution, the correct being using `:visible` but it just doesn't work on webkit

jQuery 1.6.4

Comment: I've seen a similar issue with empty tags and .is(':visible'), specifically in Chrome.<span></span> registered as false, but <span>&nbsp;</span> registered as true.

Answer (score 21):

I've got the exact problem doing a paginator using jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` to hide or show my elements. This is really a problem with chrome considering `display:inline` as hidden.

I solved it by replacing this :

```
$(whatever).filter(':visible');
```

by this :

```
$(whatever).filter(function(){ return $(this).css('display') != 'none';});
```

---

or in a function for reutilisation :

```
$(whatever).filter(visibleFilter);

function visibleFilter(){
    return $(this).css('display') != 'none';
}
```

This is really a fix for chrome and IE as it works on Firefox normally... I hope this can help  other people, having the same problem!

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I found that I could use the `filter(":visible")` if I was selecting `div`s but the filter broke down when selecting `span`s. Your solution works great for both.

Answer (score 0):

Could you test this: http://jsfiddle.net/FRFpH/

Can't reproduce your problem (tried both in IE, Chrome & FF) :/

Comment: I think I manged to break it http://jsfiddle.net/FRFpH/7/
that is far closer to the actual code, it's inside a table. Still works in FF

Comment: I believe that if the initially displayed element has a block tag (such as `<h1>` or `<p>`) then webkit acts a little strange... http://jsfiddle.net/FRFpH/8/ in this example try removing the `<p>` tag from the 3rd element and it works

Comment: Your right, so strange. Seems like display:inline is the only option bugging chrome. Playing around with it :P

Answer (score 0):

The `:hidden` selector has more to it than a simple `'display' != 'hidden'` comparison.

According to jQuery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) an element is `:hidden` if:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Especially the last bullet mentioning ancestor scoping seems like an important thing to check if you're having issues with the `:hidden` filter.

Disclaimer: the docs also state numerous changes across different jQuery versions with regards to the selector behavior.